# How to zip 100 mb files during (before) upload so that upload speed can be increased?

Tags: php, zip, unzip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML Compress File Upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939791/html-compress-file-upload)

I have complains from client that my website is taking more time to upload the 100 MB time (I know it bound to take more time because of this size), hence I am planning to upload files such that they get zipped before upload and gets uploaded to desired location and then gets unzipped along with the deletion of that zipped format uploaded file.

So can anyone suggest me how to proceed further?

I am using PHP, there is no clumsy code for uploading file its just a form with usual file upload functionalty...

> **EDIT** How could I Integrate Silverlight for this purpose in PHP?

please help

Comment: and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864908/compress-file-before-upload-via-http

Comment: I may be wrong on this, but I think the server configuration for "Accept-Encoding" or "Content-Encoding" may be worth exploring. I'd post this question to serverfault.com as well. You may have to set a request header on the page uploading the file when you initiate the transfer. It would strike me as odd that a browser that supports `gzip,deflate` and a server that supports `gzip,deflate` couldn't negotiate a compressed file upload.

Comment: One more idea... I see that [nochump.com](http://nochump.com/blog/archives/15) has an Adobe Air library that can zip and unzip files on the fly. If you have few enough clients to justify a custom uploader, this might be a good solution. It would be simple for them to use and you could use all your existing server-side code as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to manipulate the file like this with a plain html form and PHP script.  For one reason, with the browser's sandbox, there's no access to the client's filesystem.

You would probably want to explore a Java Applet, Silverlight, Flash type solution, something richer on the client that can be allowed access to the file.

[Here's one example using Silverlight](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/anton_staykov/archive/2010/04/28/implementing-simple-file-upload-using-silverlight-4-drag-amp-drop-feature-and-infragistics-compression-library.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In order to zip the file before upload it needs to be done on client side. PHP is of no use there because PHP is server-side only.

Option 1: You ask your clients to upload those files already zipped (looks like thats not what you want).

Option 2: You need a way to do it serverside by javascript code - to be honest i doubt that there is an easy solution for that if at all. Maybe a zip data stream could work, but for that special permissions for the script (f.e. ActiveX) are required - and today no upto date browser will allow that.

Comment: Thanx for the analysis Thariama... then what cold be the possible solution for uploading the 100mb file without delay...?

Comment: but as already stated i doubt it will work for new browser cause of security issues. have alook here for a brief discussion: http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10316619