# (PHP) Is there any way to split a large file into packages for uploading it?

Tags: php, file, upload, split

I've already checked post_max_size upload_max_filesize on my php.ini file, the thing is that my hosting provider doesn't allow more than 25M for each upload.

I need to let the users to upload files 50M - 100M. But before changing my provider I thought maybe there's some workaround to split large files into separate packages, upload them and then join them back together.

Any ideas will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

From [Splitting a file before upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099929/splitting-a-file-before-upload)

> You can try [Plupload][1]. It can be configured to check whatever
>   runtime is available on users side, be it - Flash, Silverlight, HTML5,
>   Gears, etc, and use whichever satisfies required features first. Among
>   other things it supports image resizing (**on users side, preserving
>   EXIF data(!)**), stream and multipart upload, and chunking. Files can
>   be chunked on users side, and sent to a server-side handler
>   chunk-by-chunk (requires some additional care on server), so that big
>   files can be uploaded to a server having max filesize limit set to a
>   value much lower then their size, for example. And more.
>
> Some runtimes support https I believe, some need testing. Anyway,
>   developers on there are quiet responsive these days. So you might at
>   least try ;)
>
> [1]: http://www.plupload.com/index.php

Comment: Agree to the solution. To give direct answer, no, there is no way to split a file before uploading, short of writing your own cross platform file splitter. Joining the files would work though.