# Is there a way to ignore the maxRequestLength limit of 2GB file uploads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

Here's where I'm setting `maxRequestLength` to 2GB (the max value), which indicates the maximum request size supported by ASP.NET:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600"/>
    ...
```

and here I'm setting the `maxAllowedContentLength` to 4GB (the max value), which specifies the maximum length of content in a request supported by IIS

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    ...
```

I'd like to be able to upload files up to 4GB, but I'm limited by the `maxRequestLength` field.

I noticed that this third party upload tool (http://www.element-it.com/onlinehelp/webconfig.html) has a `ignoreHttpRuntimeMaxRequestLength` property, which allows it to upload files up to 4GB.

Does anyone know if I can ignore the `maxRequestLength` value like this other upload tool does?

Comment: What are you using to upload? It is my understanding that you can use chunked transfer-encoding to upload larger than 2GB files because the chunked transfer-encoding does not include a content-length header, so the maxRequestLength is not used. It is also my understanding most browsers do not support chunked transfer-encoding.

Comment: Try use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12056417/551744 . I relialized splitting files with JavaScript and merging them on server side. This can help too: http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considering the Type of [MaxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx) is a [Int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w(v=vs.110).aspx), at the moment there is no way to parse a value higher than [Int.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.85).aspx) correctly.

I heard they might be increasing IIS8 but nothing concrete from Microsoft as of yet.  The only way I've seen in .Net 4.5 is to use [HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195568.aspx) which

> Gets a Stream object that can be used to read the incoming HTTP entity body, optionally disabling the request-length limit that is set in the MaxRequestLength property.

Comment: Good point, I didn't realize `maxRequestLength` was `int` and not `uint`. It would kind of make more sense for it to be a `uint` since your request length can never be negative.

Comment: As far as I understand Microsoft fixed ASP.NET upload limit but did not fix IIS: http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/2642879-maximum-upload-size-in-asp-net-is-2gb-increase-it

Comment: MaxRequestLength is in KB, the max value is 2 TB not GB. This is not the problem, but the fact that the normal buffered input stream as well as all as the multipart formdata parser etc. breaks down on more than 2GB. The only way around it is really GetBufferlessInputStream and parsing the request yourself.

Comment: @poizan42 Yes, *however* [maxAllowedContentLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462(v=vs.90).aspx) is a UINT in bytes, so the max appears to be 4gb.

Comment: Yes, however note that you can get rid of that by removing the RequestFilteringModule altogether from your site. After that you start hitting issues with the ASP.NET ISAPI modules failing on Content-Length headers larger than MAX_UINT because they insists on parsing it before handing off to your code. I got around it by using a rewrite rule to remove the Content-Length header (saving it in a server variable first). After that you need to read the request directly using a HttpWorkerRequest.

Comment: @poizan42 Good information, you may want to write your own answer here!  (I would suggest it)

Comment: @poizan42  Could you please let me know how you can remove Content-Length header in http request using IIS Url Rewrite module?

Answer (score 1):

In my case these were the changes I needed to apply:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
     <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647" />
     <security>
        <requestFiltering>
           <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
        </requestFiltering>
     </security>
</system.webServer>
```

In order to add the serverRuntime follow the intructions in the first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394838/adding-serverruntime-tag-in-webconfig-cause-500-19-error)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to override the settings inside machine.config by adding the same node into your application's web.config like so. Microsoft has some information about [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

**NOTE:** Erik Philips is right and the max size of `maxRequestLength` is 2,147,483,647 (`Int32.MaxValue`). This answer is to illustrate how to override a setting defined in machine.config (or any .config) from within your application's web.config/

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
    ...
    ...
    </system.web>
    ...
</configuration>
```

In doing this though, you might also want to increase your timeout or it might, well, time out.