# Streaming file from angularJS to ASP.NET on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, iis

I need to send large file from client in AngularJS to Server in ASP.NET (.Net Framework 4.7.1). My backend is hosted on IIS.
Because of IIS limits I'm not able to send file bigger then 2GB.

I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977830/11041310 where is the instruction how to by-pass this limitation.

I tried to setup backend like in the post and send file using Insomnia client.
I can see, that when I send large file using header "Transfer-Encoding:chunked", I can bypass this limitation and the file is uploded.

Now I'm trying to add the same header to my AngularJs client like this:

```
$http.post("/api/upload", formData, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: { 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked' }
})
```

To backend code like this:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFileAsync()
{
    var stream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using (var fileStream = File.Create("c:\\file.txt"))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
}
```

Despite of setting up header 'Transfer-Encoding' I can see in Chrome Developer Console that this header is not send and I receive 400 error.

What can I do to force sending this request chunked?

Comment: To upload files of any size you want to adopt an ajax file uploader. Such up loaders are chucked into little bite-sized parts.  They also provide a nice progress bar.  You most certainly don't want to use a simple web end point for this. With this we are able to easily upload files larger then 2 gig

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply, thank you！

Answer (score 0):

AspEnableChunkedEncoding in IIS can enable chunked encoding.

Reference link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms526005(v=vs.90)

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/enabling-8220-transfer-encoding-chunked-8221-in-the-response/ba-p/287869

Even if AspEnableChunkedEncoding is set to true, chunked transfer encoding is used only by browsers that support and have HTTP 1.1 enabled.