# Limit on a file size server side in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently uploading files in MVC4 but in my controller I tried to limit the file size to 4MB max but got the following warning

`comparison to integral constant is useless`

using [Haacks](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) example

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
if (file.ContentLength > 0)
{
if (file.ContentLength < 4000000000 )
{
   var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
   var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
   file.SaveAs(path);
 }
```

When I run the code I get the error

```
Maximum request length exceeded.
```

Since `file.ContentLength` is an `int` over which I have no control I do not know what is the way around this. Can anyone help me on how to limit the file size server side.

**Edit** To those that might want to point out that `4000000000` is `4gb` you are correct. But even if I replace it with `4000000` my action completes sucessfully but does not save the file as my `If()` is not satisfied i.e `file.ContentLength < 4000000` returns false.

**Edit** This is not a duplicate question I want to limit my file size to a certain limit not ignore the file size limit in IIS.

Comment: if file.ContentLength is a 32-bit signed integer the max value you can compare it to is 2 billion.  That would explain the particular message you got.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to ignore the maxRequestLength limit of 2GB file uploads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129746/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-the-maxrequestlength-limit-of-2gb-file-uploads)

Comment: I don't know if you are trying to upload an exact 4MB file, but remember, 4 megabytes = 4 194 304 bytes.  Have you went through the code line by line during a upload request?  Do you have error messages if one of the if statements fails?

Comment: @Tommy the IF(file.ContentLength < 4000000) is not satisfied even if the file is 100kb text file. The code executes without any stack error but does not save the file.

Comment: What is the reported file.contentLength()?  Have you attached the debugger to check the actual reported values from the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set this value in your web.config

> `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096"/>`

Comment: Note: request length isn't just file size, it's all of the request data such as form fields too. I ran into an issue where I was posting back something like 1200 fields (don't ask why).

Comment: @Nick exactly what I was thinking still +1.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using `IFormFile` you can use the following.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
{
      int fourMB = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
      var fileSize = file.Length;//Get the file length in bytes
      if (fileSize / 1048576.0 > fourMB) //1048576 (i.e. 1024 * 1024):
        {
          var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
          var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
          file.SaveAs(path);
        }
 }
```