# Set Page/Controller specific Maximum Request in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, http-post

In my webapp I am allowing users to Upload Videos and Pictures. I was running into Maximum Size Exceeded error and found the fix using this [**Maximum Request Length Exceeded**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

But my question is for my Images controller I want to keep a 4mb limit as default. I only want to apply the solution in the link to Video controller. Is this possible? Also is there a way to add a ModelState error to check the file size before uploading? My controller action looks like

```
 if (m.File == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("File", "You did not slect any file");
            return View();
        }
        if (m.File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(m.File.FileName);
            byte[] uploadedFile = new byte[m.File.InputStream.Length];
            m.File.InputStream.Read(uploadedFile, 0, uploadedFile.Length);
            // ..... Savefile and return
        }
```

However in this action I've tried `if (m.File.ContentLength > 4194304)` and it returns false until the complete file is uploaded on server. So my second question is [**how to check the file size on server without uploading**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845941/limit-on-a-file-size-server-side-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: +1 Interesting question , I'm interested in hearing how to hook on the headers arriving but before the request body arrives in ASP.NET MVC (Here is [a related PHP/NodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16167935/1348195) question I answered) - amusingly with WebAPI the solution is rather simple IIRC.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It seems there isn't a answer to this.

Comment: Your question has answered by Roei Bahumi at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327965/html-upload-max-file-size-does-not-appear-to-work