# Adding serverRuntime tag in webconfig cause 500.19 error

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows-7, iis-7.5

I have just downloaded asp.net project from TFS on my another laptop and couldn't get it to run. I have narrowed down the issue and it is something to do with my webconfig setting and setting is

```
<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="128000000" />
```

If I comment this setting error goes away but I am just wondering why I have to comment this out when it is working on my other laptop for same project.

Error I get upon adding the above mentioned tag is following
[image].

Answer (score 16):

To anyone experiencing this issue, here is what I did to solve this
issue.

- Open command prompt as administrator.
- Navigate to your web app.
- Copy/paste:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime
```

- Press enter.

If successful you'll see something like this:

```
Unlocked section
       system.webServer/serverRuntime" at configuration path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST
```

Comment: At first Powershell didnt recognize the `%windir%`, but after changing that to `C:\windows` everything worked like a charm.