# Specifying uploadReadAheadSize in ASP.NET Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

For a problem that I am facing I need to increase the uploadReadAheadSize from 49K to 10M. I am able to change IIS's setting with

```
appcmd.exe set config "MyWebServicesSite" -section:serverRuntime /uploadReadAheadSize:10485760 /commit:apphost
```

which results in the applicationhost.config containing:

```
<location path="MyWebServicesSite" allowOverride="true">
    <system.webServer>
        <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="10485760" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

However, I am publishing my app to a remote server on which I dont have direct control on IIS's setting.

How can I put this setting in Web.config?

My attempts:

1. Adding the following inside `<system.webServer>`

   ```
   <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="10485760" />
   ```

Results:  This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

2. Adding the following under `<configuration>`:

   ```
   <location path="EmsPublisherWebServicesSite" allowOverride="true">
       <system.webServer>
           <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="10485760" />
       </system.webServer>
   </location>
   ```

   Results: No effect

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Understad more about the problem now. The main problem is the setting being locked. How can it be overridden in Web.config?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394838/adding-serverruntime-tag-in-webconfig-cause-500-19-error?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

If you do not have direct access, maybe you can request the other Admin to change the entry for you.  It would be:

```
<section name="serverRuntime" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

This matches with your:

```
<system.webServer>
<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="10485760" />
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command in the command prompt as administrator:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime
```

See [Adding serverRuntime tag in webconfig cause 500.19 error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31394838)