# Website image compression

Tags: php, image, uploader

I am currently working on a website which needs images to be uploaded. I have seen some standard image uploading tools which work well, but I am looking for one that compresses on the client side before the upload has been done.

I have looked at a view, but none seem to suit. Can anyone recommend a web based client side image compression tool?

Thanks

~ Kyle

Comment: *(possibly related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864908/compress-file-before-upload-via-http - Xceed seems fitting, but needs Silverlight

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compression"? JPEG encoding? Classical compression algorithms like ZIP or RLE will not do much good on a JPG. Try Zipping a Jpeg file to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.plupload.com/. It will resize images and chunk them so your server can handle them. I don't think it will actually compress them but this might solve your problem another way.

Comment: Thats really great! Thanks for that, exactly what we need :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking mainly about JPG images.

[SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) supports client side image resizing. (i.e. reducing the number of Pixels, see Demo [here](http://demo.swfupload.org/v250beta3/resizedemo/index.php).)

Other than that, compressing the image file (as in, compressing the file's binary data using a Zip algorithm) is not going to do you much good: JPG is extremely tough to compress and usually yields only 2-3 percent's savings.

Comment: I've recently added swfupload to a project I'm working on. It was a bit tricky to setup but does multi-file image compression and it seems to be working 98% of the time. It did manage to corrupt a couple of images though so it isn't 100%. On the other hand the problem could easily be the fault of whatever crappy camera or tool made the images in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

One image compression tool i will recommend is https://optimizejpeg.com/ .It is a very very powerful online tool and i am using this currently for my website.You can compress 50 images in just few seconds and these images gets saved in a zip folder.You don't need plug in at all for this and hence this helps to speed up your website more without any hassles as we all know plug in creates excess load on your website.With this help of tool you can upload any jpg/png/gif or a ppt file.This tool helps you to compress your image drastically by reducing it to 70-80% with no losses.Colors can also be changed here and there using the existing colors of the images.To your surprise no one can view or identify the changes in the image and hence the look of the image remains the same and also get beautified.

So do enjoy using this tool and share your experiences.